# Filter content by group

Tags: organic-groups, search

I use Drupal 7 with the Search API, and the Facet API modules.

I want to create a facet that shows all OG groups. When I click on an OG group all its content associated will be draw.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the modules you described:

- Create a index containing all the nodes that are group content
- Edit the fields of this index and add a relationship to 'Groups' (at the bottom of the page)
- You will get additional (group)fields available
- Check the one named "Groups » title" and change the type to "string" (instead of default fulltext)
- In the Facet tab, make the facet available, and place the block.

This should do the trick!